# Equality Operator/Trait == for Result<T, E>

Tags: rust, traits, equality-operator

I was wondering, if I have two variables `x` and `y` of type `Result<T, E>`, how can I overload the equality operator `==` for it? So that one can easily check `x == y`. Here is some sample code, where I tried just that:

```rust
enum ErrorKind {
    OutOfRange,
    InvalidInput,
}

type MyResult = Result<i32, ErrorKind>;

impl PartialEq for MyResult {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        match (self, other) {
            (Ok(x), Ok(y)) => x == y,
            (Err(x), Err(y)) => x == y,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}

fn func(x: i32) -> MyResult {
    if x < 0 {
        return Err(ErrorKind::OutOfRange);
    } else {
        return Ok(x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = func(-1);
    let y = func(15);
    let z = func(15);

    println!("x == z --> {}", x == z);
    println!("y == z --> {}", y == z);
}
```

Unfortunately, this gives `error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types`.

I also tried `impl MyResult { ... }` (without the `PartialEq`) but that gives `error[E0116]: cannot define inherent 'impl' for a type outside of the crate where the type is defined`.

---

Is it possible to somehow overload/define operator `==` for `Result<T, E>` (generic) or `Result<i32, ErrorKind>` (specific specialisation)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `Result<T, E>` [already implements `PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-PartialEq%3CResult%3CT%2C%20E%3E%3E), so you just need to derive that trait for `ErrorKind`. The `Result` type will implement it as a consequence.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9c394baa0291c609e39227b9a145bdf2)

Comment: Oh, so I was just missing `#[derive(PartialEq)]` on my enum. This makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @Phil-ZXX That's right. You'll notice in the link to the implementation of `PartialEq` for `Result`, that there's a trait bound: `T: PartialEq, E: PartialEq`. This means that `PartialEq` is implemented for any `Result` where the inner types also implement it.

Comment: I wish the compiler was more helpful. It said `error[E0369]: binary operation == cannot be applied to type Result<i32, ErrorKind>`. So I thought this meant I had to implement my own `PartialEq` for `Result`, which I now know is not the case.

Comment: The error message is useful, but it's describing a more general problem. You're trying to implement a trait for a type you don't control. This is usually called the [orphan rule](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2015/01/14/little-orphan-impls/), and is there to prevent conflicting implementations of a method or trait -- what happens if two dependencies implement the same trait for a type in the standard library? Which method should the compiler choose.

Comment: Also, that error message in your comment, `E0369`, is helpful as well. You can't apply `==` to that `Result`, because `PartialEq` isn't implemented for it (because it's not implemented for `ErrorKind`). The other messages in your _question_, 116 and 117 are because you tried to implement `PartialEq` manually, which is where the orphan rule comes into play.

Comment: @Phil-ZXX If only you'd read the full error message, you would noted that the compiler even suggested that fix: "note: an implementation of `PartialEq` might be missing for `ErrorKind`. help: consider annotating `ErrorKind` with `#[derive(PartialEq)]" (edited to match comment's one-line).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I am not sure it is necessary to be rude about this. Unfortunately, I don't see the same suggestion on my side: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiWkF.png But if there is a way to enable extended tips/hits/suggestions, I'd be happy to do that.

Comment: @Phil-ZXX I didn't mean to be rude, sorry if it sounded like. It is strange because the playground [does show the suggestion](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=897b695b4bb4ced26441122923dda98a). What version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman No worries at all. I am glad you pointed this out. I was on `1.56.1 (59eed8a2a 2021-11-01)`. So I updated to `rustc 1.57.0 (f1edd0429 2021-11-29)` and now I see the useful tip: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVek.png :) Thank you